# 'Invalid Syntax' error with two methods in Django views.py

Tags: django, django-views

I have two methods defined in views.py. the first one calls the second one:

```
@login_required 
def form1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          obj = form.save(commit=False)
          obj.user = request.user
          obj.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect(job)
    else:
        return render_to_response('sync_form.html', {'form': form})

def job(request):   #I get the error right here
    cmd = '/root/test.sh'
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    in_progress = p.communicate()
    return render_to_response('job.html', {'in_progress': in_progress})
```

I get 'Invalid Syntax' where I define the second method. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the indentation on line 6 supposed to be broken like that?

Comment: woops, no, I mistyped when submitting the question. edited. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to pass a rendered template as a HttpResponseRedirect argument, which will break  things.

Change:

`return HttpResponseRedirect(job)`

to:

`return job(request)`

And that may well sort it.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. This solved it as well as other problems that arised.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably a indentation error. Search and replace all tabs by 4 spaces then checks for inconsistencies in indentation.